# Grammar check using NLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I want to check if a sentence has a specific parts of speech tag structure . Can I do it using python Natural language toolkit ? If so , how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code out. With NLTK package in python, you can define

```
import nltk
sentence = "I want to check if a sentence has a specific parts of speech tag structure."
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
grammar = r"""
NP: 
{<NNS><IN><NN><NN><NN>}
{<PRP><VBP>}
"""

cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(tagged)
print result
```

Result will be like this

```
(S
  (NP I/PRP want/VBP)
  to/TO
  check/VB
  if/IN
  a/DT
  sentence/NN
  has/VBZ
  a/DT
  specific/JJ
  (NP parts/NNS of/IN speech/NN tag/NN structure/NN)
  ./.)
```

As you can see that, it gives nltk tree as an output in which `(NP parts/NNS of/IN speech/NN tag/NN structure/NN)` is combined with one single tag called "NP" as defined in our grammar. This structure you can define as per your requirement. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`spaCy` is an easy-to-use interface for NLP and POS-tagging. You can easily extract the parts of speech using `spaCy`. The code snipped below is from their website (slightly adapted to only look at POS):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'They told us to duck.')
for word in doc:
    print(word, word.tag, word.tag_, word.pos, word.pos_)
```

This returns:

```
They 479 PRP 93 PRON
told 489 VBD 98 VERB
us 479 PRP 93 PRON
to 486 TO 92 PART
duck 474 NN 90 NOUN
. 453 . 95 PUNCT
```

Comment: The example code here is correct as SpaCy code for the NLTK code above, but this also shows a drawback of using just simple POS-tagging for grammatical analysis: "duck" tagged as `NOUN` instead of `VERB`.